# Using local databases without having the end user download LocalDB

Tags: c#, database, localdb, local-database

Is there a way to use a local database without the end user having to download LocalDB on their pc ?

Comment: You have an application with a database that resides on the application user's computer through sql server express... they need an engine on their computer so the application can interface with that bundled database, so they would need to, at the least, have localdb installed... unless I'm missing something here. I would just bundle that up in the installation file as a prerequisite or redistributable or what have you so it's taken care of for them.

Comment: Is SQLite an option?

Comment: I wouldn't mind using SQLite.

Comment: **There are many databases engine available.** Some are easier to install with an application than other. Some are easier to use for software development. Some are more scalable. Some have limited database size. And if you already have done development using a given database, changing it might be time consuming depending on the tools that were used.

Comment: @Phil1970 Can you suggest some in terms of not having the end user install anything extra. and about changing the database im just re-visiting an old project of mine trying to do it better and learn from it.

Comment: **If you want a database, then it must be installed**. Select one that is easy to include in your application installer. **Any application should have an installer** so that an entry appears in the **Apps** and then user can uninstall it. If you only have small amount of data, you could also use JSON files instead of a real database.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda. There are in Process Databases - also known as [Embedded databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database). Databases that work entirely within the Application they are part off and the devices long file storage. They are often used as the layer of a [Distributed Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_database) that is closest to the enduser. A relatively new term for this seems to be [Mobile Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_database), as it is used very often in Mobile Applications.

I doubt you get around eventually downloading the entire DB, but it can at least be done picemeal as requests are send. Or be largely done once over a fast connection like WLAN, rather then a slow and expensive Mobile Data Uplink.